# Calling Async methods in Page_Load asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

Hi i am new to using **async** and **await** in asynchronous methods,
and i want call few calls which are happening in `page_load` as asynchronous.

here is the code..

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string UrlData = ReadAsync().Result;

    //continuation code..
 }

 protected async Task<string> ReadAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Task<string> T = getFinalValue();
    await T;

    return T.Result;
 }

 protected async Task<string> getFinalValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //my code to create string
     return "created string";
 }
```

and

1.i need to understand is this correct way or not ?

2.using `ReadAsync().Result` in synchronous method is correct or leads to any other isuues ?

3.do i need `ReadAsync` method in between to serve this or can i use directly `getFinalValue` inside the `page_load` and how to use it ?

4.And can i keep `page_load` as synchronous or asynchronous ? which is better way ?

any responses would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Classic ASP.NET doesn't really play that well with async, you'll need to change it to something like...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(ReadAsync));
}

protected async Task ReadAsync()
{
    string UrlData = await getFinalValue();

    //continuation code..
}

protected async Task<string> getFinalValue()
{
    //my code to create string
     return "created string";
}
```

See Scott Hanselman's post on this topic...

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

Comment: what if i want return string into **void**  from `ReadAsync` ?

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible.  There are some pretty big limitations to using async within a classic ASP.NET Web forms applicaiton

Comment: Sorry I dont know of good information on this topic.  I think there is limited support for async in ASP.NET web forms, compared with MVC/Web API where it is much better supported.